# Issue with css transitions under an image

Tags: html, css

I made an example of the problems i'm having.

The idea is to have a webpage split in 2, the left side using css transitions and the right side with the actual content.

Case 1:
http://generowicz.nl/testing/Untitled-1.html

Here i made a gray image fill the whole left side and when you mouse-over it completely transparent, revealing a more clear menu. The links (in this case "Test") are supposed to have mouseover transitions as well (as is shown in the top "Scroll" text) but they do not work because the image is over the text and so no mouseover is registered. I tried looking in to    "pointer-events" which make it so you can select the text behind the image but the transitions no longer trigger on the image since it is a pointer-event.

To "fix" this i tried using :hover::before, the result of this is:

Case 2: http://generowicz.nl/testing/Untitled-4.html

Here the link and the foreground transition both work except that the foreground is no longer over the text links.

I hope i made it clear enough,

Code 1

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#left{
 text-indent:1.5cm;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    outline: 1px solid;
 background: rgba(51,51,51,0.9);
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

#right {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    outline: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: white;
}

#img {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.8;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
 color:#000;
}

#img:hover {
 opacity: 0;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 80px;
 color:#CCC;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #CCC;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

 

a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 1s ease-out;
}  

a:link:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #09F;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 1s ease-out;
    }
    
a:visited:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #09F;
}
a:active { text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"><img src="graysmall.png" name="img" width="93" height="55" id="img" />
  <h2> B </h2>
  <h3><a href="../index.html">Test</a></h3>

</div>
<div id="right"><a href="../index.html">Scroll</a><br />
  Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <p> <a href="../index.html">Scroll</a></p>
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />
</div>
```

Code2 :

```css
a:link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 1s ease-out;
}  

a:link:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #09F;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 1s ease-out;
    }
    
a:visited:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #09F;
}
a:active { text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
 background: rgba(51,51,51, 1);
 position:fixed;
 color:#CCC;
 text-indent:1.5cm;
}
#right {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
 color:#CCC;
 text-indent:1.5cm;
}
#left:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: rgba(51,51,51, 0.8); /*partially transparent image*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    pointer-events: none;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;   Saf3.2+, Chrome 
     -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;   FF4+ 
      -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;   IE10 
       -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;   Opera 10.5+ 
          transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#left:hover::before {
 position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: rgba(51,51,51, 0); /*partially transparent image*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 80px;
 color: #CCC;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #CCC;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <h2>B</h2>
  <h3><a href="../index.html">Home</a></h3>
</div>
<div id="right"><br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll
    <br />Scroll</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your first example, set the `pointer-events` property of the `#img` element to `none` and then change the `#img:hover` selector to `#left:hover>#img`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#left {
  text-indent: 1.5cm;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#right {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}
#img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events:none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
  color: #000;
}
#left:hover>#img {
  opacity: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #CCC;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #CCC;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  Saf3.2+, Chrome -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  FF4+ -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  IE10 -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  Opera 10.5+ transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
a:link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #09F;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  Saf3.2+, Chrome -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  FF4+ -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  IE10 -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  Opera 10.5+ transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
a:visited:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #09F;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  Saf3.2+, Chrome -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  FF4+ -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  IE10 -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  Opera 10.5+ transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <img src="graysmall.png" name="img" width="93" height="55" id="img" />
  <h2> B </h2>
  <h3><a href="../index.html">Test</a></h3>

</div>
<div id="right"><a href="../index.html">Scroll</a>
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <p> <a href="../index.html">Scroll</a>
  </p>
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />Scroll
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what i wanted